# How do I match for only one instance of a word in a string?

Tags: regex, perl, match

How do I match for only one instance of a word in a string?
As an example, with "fred" as my test word, match should be TRUE for the string "fredwilmawilliamjohn" but should be FALSE for "fredwilmawilliamfred"?

Comment: If you're doing the exercises in _Learning Perl_, you should do them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of matches by using the `/g` flag in list context, and converting that into scalar context.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

for my $string (qw(fredwilmawilliamjohn fredwilmawilliamfred) ) {
    my $count = () = $string =~ m/(fred)/g;
    if ( $count  == 1 ) {
        say $string;
    }
}
```

The most relevant part is the `= () =`, which forces the match into *list context*. The `my $count` will then force that list of matches into scalar context, which gives you the number of items in the list. That's your number of matches.

Comment: can it done using purely regexp?                                 
$_="fredwilliamwilma";
if(/regexp/)
{print "there is only one fred in the string"}

Comment: @SKS you mean you want to put all the logic into the pattern? Fred and negative look ahead for nothing or anything followed by fred, I guess. Don't have a computer now. You'll have to try yourself.

Comment: `= () =` is also known as the 'goatse operator' :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/fred(*COMMIT)(?!.*?fred)/s
```

`(*COMMIT)` (added in perl 5.10) says after matching `fred`, don't backtrack and try matching it again if the remainder of the regex fails.  The rest of the regex says don't match if `.*?fred` (any number of any characters followed by fred) matches at that point, after the first fred, i.e. there is no further fred.

Before 5.10, you would need to force the first fred in the regex to only match the first fred in the string like so:

```
/^(?:(?!fred).)*+fred(?!.*?fred)/s
```

(match any number of characters so long as they aren't the beginning of fred before matching the fred that cannot then be followed by another fred).

Or

```
/^(?>.*?fred)(?!.*?fred)/s
```

(start at the beginning of the string and, without allowing backtracking, find the first fred, and assert that there is not a fred after it)

(Throughout, /s is used to make `.` match any character, not just any non-newline character.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to match the pattern and verify that it doesn't occur subsequently in the string. How about this, using negative lookahead

```
m/fred(?!.*fred)/
```

Breaking it down:

?! -- not followed by

.* -- zero or more characters

Comment: This won't work because the regexp will try to make the negative lookahead succeed. If it can find anything in the string not matching the second fred, the regex succeeds. `!m/fred(?=.*fred)/` would work here.

Comment: @ChrisCharley correct in principle, but you aren't quite saying it right.  this regex will keep it from matching the first fred, but the beginning of the regex will be  it tried further on in the string and match the second fred (which doesn't have a fred after it)

Comment: @ysth Thank you for clarifying my error. I see exactly now how the regexp functions.